# Avoid "null" Brush in a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, designer, coercion

I have a custom control that has a `DependencyProperty` of type `Brush` (is a Background color like property).

The user is so able to set the color using the standard Visual Studio Color Property Bag.
What I want is to exclude the possibility to set a null brush (the one with the barred box).
I tried to use the `CoerceValue` callback in this way:

```
MyBackgroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyBackgroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, null, CoerceCurrentColor));
```

where `CoerceCurrentColor` is:

```
private static object CoerceCurrentColor(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if (baseValue == null)//Null brush can't be permitted
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

    return baseValue as Brush;
}
```

This works ...the first time only.

If I select "No Brush", the real color is set to Transparent. But now everytime I try to change the color I get an "Invalid Property Value" message box error. Why? And, is there an alternative way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Use IValueConverter to handle the null possibility.

Comment: Nice idea! I'll try it soon and I'll let you know